# pausing program without interrupting timers c#

Tags: c#, timer, pausing-execution

I am writing a program that has several "Worker" objects going off and doing tasks that take as set amount of time.  I have created a worker class with an internal timer that is working fine.  However, when doing the "work" i will at times need to wait several seconds for a screen refresh (each worker is scraping data from a remote screen and doing some automation).

For those pauses, i don't want to sleep the thread, because as i understand it that will also 
pause the timers on the other worker objects (my application is a single thread because, frankly, I'm brand new to C# and i didn't want to overreach).  Is there another waiting function that i can use that doesn't actually hang the whole thread?

Some additional info:

- Right now this is a console app, but i will eventually be building a UI form to provide feedback to the user on how the workers are doing
- My timers are implemented using System.Timers and are working quite nicely
- I am brand new to C# programming, this is my first project, so please use small words ;)
- Using MS VS Express 2012 for Desktop (so whatever version of C# / .NET that is!)

Code below (the actual work will be done using the "startWorking" method, but nothing is implemented - this is just my sold build with timers working.  Also, the main is just being used for testing multiple timers right now)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Multi_Timers
{
//worker class that includes a timer
public class Worker
{
    private Timer taskTimer;
    private bool available = true;
    private string workerName;
    private string startWork;
    private int workTime;

    // properties
    public bool isAvailable { get { return this.available; } }
    public string name { get { return this.workerName; } }

    // constructor
    public Worker(string name)
    {
        this.workerName = name;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is initialized", name);
    }

    // start work timer
    public void startWorking(int duration) {

        if (this.available == true)
        {
            this.available = false;
            this.taskTimer = new Timer();
            this.taskTimer.Interval = duration;
            this.taskTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(doneWorking);
            this.taskTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.startWork = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            this.workTime = duration / 1000;
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Sorry, {0} was not available to work", this.workerName);
    }

    // Handler for timer
    public void doneWorking(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} / {2} min / {3}", this.workerName, this.startWork, this.workTime/60, e.SignalTime.ToLocalTime());
        this.taskTimer.Enabled = false;

        this.available = true;

    }
}

//main program
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        // initialize worker(s)
        Worker bob = new Worker("Bob");
        Worker bill = new Worker("Bill");
        Worker jim = new Worker("Jim");

        // q to exit
        while (true)
        {
            if (bob.isAvailable) {

                bob.startWorking(r.Next(1 * 60, 150 * 60) * 1000);
            }
            if (bill.isAvailable)
            {
                bill.startWorking(r.Next(1 * 60, 150 * 60) * 1000);
            }
            if (jim.isAvailable)
            {
                jim.startWorking(r.Next(1 * 60, 150 * 60) * 1000);
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance! Reading examples from this community was definitely key in teaching myself a little bit of C# to get started with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i don't want to sleep the thread, because as i understand it that will also pause the timers on the other worker objects

That is incorrect; it will not stop the timers.

> my application is a single thread

No, actually, it's not.  The timers will be creating and using other threads to implement their behavior.  The `Elapsed` event handlers will be fired from a thread pool thread.

---

One major issue with your code is that your `main` method is doing a "busywait" on the three objects, constantly polling them asking if they're done.  This is...expensive.  It's basically like you're kids asking, "Are we there yet." a few hundred times a second.  Wouldn't it be so much nicer if they just sat their waiting until you told them you were done!  (That's quite possible, and a good possible option.)

One of the simpler solutions in this case would be to do the loop in the worker, not `Main`.  Have the implementation of `startWorking` wrapped in a `while` loop, and have main just do a wait forever (i.e. `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);`).  More complex options would be having the workers provide a `Task`, event, or blocking wait (also called a "Join") method to indicate when they are finished.

The option you're considering, that of adding a `Thread.Sleep` of a little while in `Main` will *help*, but it's only telling your kids to ask you when you're there less often, rather than having them wait for you to tell them when you're there.

Comment: thanks, i had no idea they auto-spawned threads for themselves, this is great! For the main stuff, i appreciate the advice on a few different approaches as well.  For now, its really just testing my methods, definitely going to do something way more elegant with it in the future!

Answer (score -1):

If you ever find yourself wanting to delay execution again in a different context you could consider an implementation like this:

```
private static void DelayExecution(Action action, TimeSpan delay)
{
    TimeSpan start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < start.Add(delay))
        {
            //Block
        }
        action.Invoke();
    });
    t.Start();
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DelayExecution(() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed Execution"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```